# Is there a difference between getTransaction().begin()/.commit() and joinTransaction() with JPA2/EclipseLink?

Tags: java, database, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I'm using JPA2 with annotations and EclipseLink and I'm wondering if there is a difference between

```
EntityManager em = ...
// Some action
em.joinTransaction();
em.close();
```

and

```
EntityManager em = PU.entityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
// Some action
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

and which one should I generally prefer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`EntityManager.joinTransaction`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#joinTransaction%28%29) is meant to be used for JTA transactions (implying that the persistence unit is configured to use JTA transactions) whereas [`EntityTransaction.begin`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityTransaction.html#begin%28%29) is meant to be used for resource-local entity managers (implying the non-usage of JTA to manage transactions). Therefore, they're both meant to be used in different scenarios.

The first case, i.e. `EntityManager.joinTransaction` is rarely used, for you would often inject container-managed `EntityManager` instances when you need JTA transaction support. Container-managed `EntityManager`s are injected (using the [`@PersistenceContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) annotation) into the context of an existing JTA transaction (managed by the container) and hence there is no need to explicitly join a transaction. It is only in the event of application-managed `EntityManager`s that you need to join an existing transaction. Application managed `EntityManager`s are not injected by the container; instead the container may only inject an `EntityManagerFactory` instance (using the [`@PersistenceUnit`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceUnit.html) annotation) that is used by the application to obtain the `EntityManager` instance.

In the second case, i.e. `EntityTransaction.begin`, no JTA transactions will be used to scope any transactional work. Instead, the transaction is resource-local in that any changes made to the persistence context are tracked as an atomic unit until `EntityTransaction.commit` is invoked. One would rarely use resource-local entity managers in a Java EE application, as you would typically want EJBs (and the EJB container) to demarcate the transaction boundaries, and not the application source code. Also, any transactional work performed using a resource-local transaction will not be tracked by a JTA transaction that might already have been initiated, thereby resulting in vague , confusing and ambiguous behavior regarding the transactional activities in your application.

Comment: So in a non-Java-EE application `begin`/`commit` is the way to go?

Comment: Yes, that would be right. In case my answer wasn't clear enough, `joinTransaction` is only meant to be invoked if the a JTA entity manager is not already associated with a JTA transaction.